# Overlay raster above uploaded shpfile but behind background?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgsmapcanvas, qgsvectorlayer

I have a .shp file of the world oceans (hydropolys.shp) and create a map with it in QGIS, so the background of the image is the land. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can overlay my raster output on top of the oceans, but not overlain on the land? So I essentially want my image overlain on top of the uploaded .shp file but underneath the background.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the map canvas background in front of a map layers. What you *can* do, is create a land layer and put it in front of the raster image.

Since you already have oceans, you don't even need new data.

1. Duplicate the ocean layer: right click on the layer name 'hydropolys', choose "duplicate layer" from the menu.

   [image]

   Now you have a new layer called 'hydropolys copy'.
2. Style 'hydropolys copy' with an inverted polygon fill. This will shade in all of the area *outside* the oceans, IE the land.  Match the fill color to the color of your map canvas background.

   [image]
3. Arrange the layers in the Layers panel in this order:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks! Are there matching commands for writing this in PyQGIS so I can skip this process and create the land layer directly in PyQGIS?

Comment: There probably are matching commands in pyqgis, but I don't know them. I hear there's a pyqgis manual, though. That seems like the place to go if you want to learn how to code in pyqgis.

Comment: Can I export the new hydropolys copy into a shp file?

Comment: There's no need to create a new layer, because it's the same data with a different style. If you export 'hydropolys copy' you're just creating a copy of the 'hydropolys' shapefile.

Comment: I have another question sorry. I want to export the inverted polygon layer so the shapefile has the land as the vector layer to use in Pyqgis. Can I do this or will it just export the same shape file?

Comment: It's the same data, so exporting it will just create a duplicate of the same data. If you want the land as a layer, that's a whole [other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).